# mongodb read, copy, process and delete

Tags: mongodb

I have to write an app that constantly polls a mongodb db collection in a given db. If it finds documents it reads them copies them to another db, does some extra processing  and deletes them from the original db.

What is the most efficient way to implement this? What are the best practices?

Is it better to process one doc at a time: read one document, copy the document then delete it
or is it better to read all documents, copy all of them, then delete all of them?

What would be the best way to handle failures in the middle of one of these read, write deletes?

Comment: Reading and inserting are very basic operations and this approach sounds very straightforward. Is there anything specific you're concerned about, e.g. performance, scalability? As it stands it's really hard to write anything meaningful as an answer other than "yes" or a "here's a link to getting started with MongoDB".

Comment: I would be a good idea to use batch processing here, taking documents in batches of maybe 100 working on them and then deleting them. Best way to handle error depends on the work being done in the documents

Answer (score 0):

Bulk reads, inserts and deletes are almost always more performant than single document actions. But try to limit it to a maximum number of documents, e.g. in our setup 500 seemed to be optimal.

For handling errors, you could use the following pseudo transaction pattern:

1. findAndModify while setting "state":"pending" for all read documents
2. process documents
3. bulk insert
4. delete all documents with "state":"pending"

If something goes wrong in the processing part or the bulk insert, you can unlock all locked documents and try again.

A more elaborate example of these kind of psuedo transactions can be found in the MongoDB Tutorial:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/